# form_tag isn't working when upgraded to rails 3.0.7 --> 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Just upgraded to rails 3.1 and now my form_tag doesn't work anymore, I don't get any errors at all?

```
    <% form_tag({:action => 'search'}, :remote => true) do %>
        <%= select_tag "prod_id", options_for_select(["-"]) %>
        ...
    <% end %>
```

Have something dramatically changed so I need to change my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at development.log - is there any error in there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code blocks in your views (like `form_for`, for instance) now need to use the `<%= %>` syntax instead of `<% %>`.

Change the first line of your code to look like this:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => 'search'}, :remote => true) do %>
```

and you should be good to go.

As a note, I think this change actually came about in one of the Rails 3.0 betas.  Check out http://asciicasts.com/episodes/208-erb-blocks-in-rails-3 for a bit of documentation on it.

Comment: Yeah, I only noticed this issue when I upgraded to Rails 3.1 as well - it also worked for me in 3.0.x.  I'm guessing the "old" syntax was just deprecated in 3.0.x and completely unsupported in 3.1?